# Does it make sense to make messenger on blockchain?

Tags: ether

Chatting, messaging usually implies privacy. Does it make sense to send transactions that are visible on blockchain to everyone?

Or the content of messages is not visible to everyone, just the fact that 2 people exchanged messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Privacy won't be a big problem, as the messages can always be encrypted. A bigger problem is probably implementing a messaging protocol, as there is no guarantee that a message

- will eventually be included in a block
- the cost is acceptable
- the order of the inclusion is inline with how that chat happened
- the inclusion happens in time to make a meaningful chat.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ethereum's decentralized nodes for relaying messages is a possibility when POS comes into play. It would be impractical to store all your messages on the blockchain as that would not scale. One good example of a blockchain messenger is the session messenger, http://getsession.org -- it's a fork of the Signal messenger with a blockchain backend but doesn't need its native token to operate.